# How to store float values in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to perform some numerical approximations on a physics problem. To speed up the process, I used tensorflow on some GPUs.

I get an expectation value from a matrix, which should be a float.
I then want to store these individual values in a tensor and then input it into a dataframe.

```
def Expectation_Value(density,N):
    expec=0
    for i in np.arange(1,N+1):
        a=tf.linalg.trace(tf.matmul(Sigma(i,N,Sz),density))
        expec+=a
    return expec/N

def main():
    df=pd.read_csv('.....')
    for l in range(len(df))
        sess=tf.Session()
        Sz_tens=tf.zeros(len(df))
        Expec=Expectation_Value(DMT,N)
        Sz_tens[l]=Expec
    Sz_arr=Sz_tens.eval(session=sess)
    df['Sz']=Sz_arr
    sess.close()
    df.head()
```

I get the following error

TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Is it possible to store individual values in a tensor? I get the impression that I don't understand how to run tensorflow graph sessions correctly.

The numerical code works perfectly, I'm just struggling to store the data in a tensor.

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: No, tensors in TensorFlow are immutable. You must produce the tensor you want through tensor operations. Please provide a minimal, self-contained example of what you are trying to do. Also, if you just want to use the GPU for some computation, you may also consider [PyCUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda) or [Numba for CUDA GPUs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/) if it's something simple.